# Can I use separate non connection pool data source for long running but infrequent tasks?

Tags: spring, hibernate, connection-pooling

My application stack consists of Spring MVC, Hibernate and MySQL hosted on Apache tomcat 7.

I have set up Spring to manage transactions and Hibernate session factory is utilizing the tomcat dbcp connection pool backed datasource for getting the connection.

I have a use case in my application in which I have a run a long running task which is initiated through the web UI (say a button click). This task runs for let’s say 10 minutes then my connection pool starts to throw connection closed exceptions. This is obviously because of connection pool setting in which if the connection is not returned to pool after a specific time, it is marked as abandoned and later removed. I could solve this by tinkering with the timeout settings and increasing it to a large enough value. But I may have several other use cases like this and may not currently have idea how long those will run.

So I am thinking of another approach here.

This use case will be initiated not very often, so I may use a separate datasource definition without using connection pool. Of course I can set two transaction managers in Spring with different names “abc” and “xyz” and use the @Transactional(name=”abc”) and @Transactional(name=”xyz)”. Both these transaction managers would use their respective datasources – one with connection pool to support common use cases and one without connection pool to support long running transaction. This way I won’t have to worry about changing the timeout configurations.

Will this be a generally accepted solution or should I take the timeout configuration approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoiding to use the connection pool will cause problems if you don't have another way to limit the number of connections that your application can initiate. For example (trivial example of cours) if your going to launch your batch process each time a user clicks a button, make sure you limit the times they can do this task.

Another way would be to define a new jdbc resource in your application server (jdbc/batchprocess) and configure in this resource a longer timeout. Then change from one to another using [dynamic datasource routing](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/).

Comment: Your point about connection pool is valid ! Also thanks for pointing to dynamic datasource routing. Seems promising. I'll have a look and come back.

Answer (score 1):

You can open Hibernate Sessions, supplying your own Connection:

```
sessionFactory.withOptions().connection( yourConnection ).openSession();
```

Comment: Do you you mean that "yourConnection" should come from a non pooled data source ?

Comment: Correct.  The only thing to watch out for is transaction handling.  If you configure Hibernate to use JTA-based transactions, would be best to register that connection you pass in with the TM; etc.  But in general the `yourConnection` could come from anywhere...